# Language translator from English to Kannada

Tags: machine-translation

I want to develop a translator which takes English text as input and gives output in Kannada (Regional language of Karnataka). I want to know which  programming language to use for coding. Do such translators already exist?

Answer (score 1):

you can embed google translate into your website go to https://translate.google.com/ and pick your language - kannada is supported - and embed the script into your code.

Google translate have been ahead you for a while, i'm afraid your undertaking would be a bit redundant.